# Calculating momentum signal for stock prices in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have monthly closing prices of stocks that I would like to use to build a portfolio based on their momentum signals; where momentum is calculated as the percentage change of stock price from 12 months ago to 1 month ago.

For example, the momentum signal for a stock in December 2011 would be
= (Price in December 2010)/(Price in November 2011) - 1

I've tried doing

```
df.pct_change().resample('Y').agg(lambda x: (x+1).prod() - 1)
```

but this calculates the change from 12 months ago to the current month as opposed to my desired 1 month ago.

What is a good way to do this in pandas or numpy?

Comment: Will you show an example `df`?

Comment: `df.shift(1) / df.shift(12) - 1`

Answer (score 0):

To calculate the return momentum over a specific period, you should use the cumulative product of the daily returns, hers's an example:

```
price_data = pd.DataFrame({'close': [100, 105, 110, 108, 115, 120, 118, 122, 124, 130]})

price_data['return'] = price_data['close'].pct_change()
```

Calculate return momentum for different time periods:

```
price_data['30_day_momentum'] = (1 + price_data['return']).rolling(window=30).apply(lambda x: x.prod()) - 1
```